# What is difference between org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, mainframe, db2-connect

I was connecting to DB2 systems using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and I have 
found that `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource` is more extensive as it allows me to generate traces.

Now I would like to know the difference more accurately and which is preferable as I believe that `BasicDataSource` is light as compared to `DB2DataSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource is actually a connection *pool*, from which you can borrow/return connections to any flavour of database: Oracle, Sybase, DB2, etc.

com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource is a DB2 data source.

So, you could have a DBCP pool of perhaps 100 DB2 connections.  The pool will return you a pretty generic datasource for use in your code - unless you cast it explicitly to a DB2 one e.g. in order to get access to its fuller API. Edit following comment below: you shouldn't really need to do this, normal idiom of use is to go with the regular DataSource interface.

Read more about DBCP and its configuration options at:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/index.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html

Comment: +1 but I would advise against casting. Use as generic an interface as possible; maybe you think you're never going to migrate to a different database, but there's a lot of future out there.

Comment: agreed; would advise casting as a last resort, usually the plain DataSource interface should be enough, a valuable clarification